# cannot install php7.3-mysqli

Tags: php7

I have installed PHP 7.3 on my Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and in order to run some web applications with Mysql I believe I need `php7.3-mysqli`.  When I run

sudo apt install php7.3-mysqli

apt insists on installing `php7.3-mysql` not mysqli.  The applications do not run, and I have seen references to `mysqli` being required.  How can I get apt to install the extension I want?

Comment: Did you restart PHP-FPM after installing `php7.3-mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether you actually have PHP 7.3 installed. Ubuntu / Kubuntu 18.04 comes with PHP 7.2 by default, so the package name would be `php7.2-mysql`. In case you installed PHP 7.3 from a PPA or some other repository, you might want to check the name of the package in that repo (though there's a good chance that the package's called `php7.3-mysql`).

Secondly, the package `php7.2-mysql` contains the `mysqli` functions, among others. You might say, the package contains all bundled PHP extensions for working with MySQL, and [there are several](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php). Just because the (very) old style `mysql_` functions were removed doesn't mean that the name of the package changed.

Thirdly, after you installed a new package with PHP extensions, you need to restart the services in question so they "know about" the new functionality. At least the webserver (Apache, NGINX, ...) needs to be restarted. If you're using a separate PHP service like PHP-FPM, you need to restart that, too. The details depend on how you set up your server.